# Resizing needs Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So What I am trying to do is I have 3 `div` each `div` should scroll over the another `div` and when it reaches the top it's position should be fixed.

So everything is working fine until we resize the window(It needs refresh of page). 
How to fix this ? I mean can't we do this without refreshing the page ?

I used resize but it's not working for me. And I'm not sure whether this is the right way of using resize

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Veeraj_P/MyM28/3/) copy of my work

```
var $cache = $('#two');
var $cache2=$('#three');

var vTop = $cache.offset().top - parseFloat($cache.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
var vTop2 = $cache2.offset().top - parseFloat($cache2.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var vTop = $cache.offset().top - parseFloat($cache.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
        var vTop2 = $cache2.offset().top - parseFloat($cache2.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
 });

  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y >= vTop) {     
      $cache.addClass('stuck');
      $('#one').addClass('stuck');
      $('#two h2').addClass('stuck');     
    } else if(y>=vTop2)
    {
         $('#two h2').removeClass('stuck');
    }
      else {
      $cache.removeClass('stuck');
      $('#one').removeClass('stuck');
       $('#two h2').removeClass('stuck');       
    }
  });
```

Comment: post relevant code here, not only in jsfiddle!

Comment: Why you should reload the page after resizing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onresize` to handle elements:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
//handling code in between
}
```

Comment: _I mean can't we do this without refreshing the page ?_